# Find similarities in a binary string

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, binary, compare

I am currently trying to write a function that would help me find similarities between binary strings. This sounds vague so I will explain with an example.

```
StringA : 10111010000
StringB : 10111010011
StringC : 10111101111
```

I want my program to be able to find any similarities (4 digits or more) occuring at the same index. In the above example, my function would return : 0-4 (because caracters 0 to 4 are identical in all three strings).

I am not looking for code, just a logical and optimal way of doing this.

Comment: If you aren't looking for code, don't add language tags (like C# or vb.net).

Answer (score 1):

String is Array of Char.

You should do Loop in which you would compare each char.

For Example: (I had to put example, sorry)

```
for(int i=0;i<=length;i++) \\length = array lenght
{
    if(StringA[i]==StringB[i]) CounterA++; \\or something like this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

method 1: split the strings into either an Array, or a List, then use LINQ to find the groupings within the list...

method 2: loop through each string, then through each character, then create a new string with the character length, and compare to the same substring on the other strings...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all three items are stored in their own respective variables, I would split all of the bits into an array. From there, I would iterate through one array (since all of the arrays are the same size) and match from there. This operation would be `O(n)` since you have to look at `n` items.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode?

array := array[numbers]

for each binary number
 for each binary number
  if numbers have the same binary digit at current index
   array[index] := array[index] + 1
  end
 end
end

Answer (score 0):

Iterate each character in the string, if they match add to a counter:

```
private static int GetDifferences(string firstStr, string secondStr)
{
    int val = 0;

    char[] first = firstStr.ToCharArray();
    char[] second = secondStr.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
    {
        if (first[i] == second[i])
        {
            val++;
        }
    }

    return val;
}
```

By no means perfect but should get you started

Answer (score 0):

i'd split them into a list:

```
static void Main()
{
    var a = "10111010000";
    var b = "10111010011";
    var c = "10111101111";

   var aList = Split(a, 4); //Use a custom split method
   var bList = Split(b, 4);
   var cList = Split(c, 4);

   Dictionary<int,string> hits = new Dictionary<int, string>();

   for (int i = 0; i < aList.Count(); i++)
   {
       if(aList[i] == bList[i] && bList[i] == cList[i])
           hits.Add(i,aList[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could use Bitwise operators:

1. get XOR result from A/B (say:A^B) and A/C (say:A^C)
2. get NOT result of step 1: ~(A^B); ~(A^C)
3. get And result from step 2: (~(A^B))&(~(A^C))
4. get the 1 part from step 3.

e.g.:

1.

```
      A^B=10111010000^
          10111010011
         =00000000011;
      A^C=10111010000^
          10111101111
         =00000111111
```

2.

```
    ~(A^B)=~(00000000011)=11111111100;
    ~(A^C)=~(00000111111)=11111000000;
```

3.

```
    (~(A^B))&(~(A^C)) =11111111100&
                       11111000000
                      =11111000000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were just wanting to get a true or false as to whether there is a minimum of 4 matching characters, you could do this:

```
Public Function StringsHaveMin4CharsInCommon(ByVal StringA As String, ByVal StringB As String, ByVal StringC As String) As Boolean
Dim bReturn As Boolean
Dim iCounter As Integer

For i As Integer  = 0 To StringA.Length - 1

If StringA.SubString(i, 1) = StringB.SubString(i, 1) And StringB.SubString(i, 1) = StringC.SubString(i, 1) Then iCounter += 1

    If iCounter = 4 Then 
        bReturn = True
        Exit For
    End If 

Next i

Return bReturn

End Function
```

If you wanted to retrieve the matching array indices then you would need to add logic to the same procedure to add each matching index to an Integer array and return that array from the function as follows.

```
Public Function GetCommonIndices(ByVal StringA As String, ByVal StringB As String, ByVal StringC As String) As Integer()
Dim iReturn() As Integer
Dim iCounter As Integer = -1

For i As Integer  = 0 To StringA.Length - 1

    If StringA.SubString(i, 1) = StringB.SubString(i, 1) And StringB.SubString(i, 1) = StringC.SubString(i, 1) Then 

        iCounter += 1
        ReDim Preserve iReturn(iCounter)
        iReturn(iCounter) = i

    End If 

Next i

Return iReturn

End Function
```

The function will return Nothing if there are no matching indices.

The functions only test for the length of StringA so it will throw an error if either StringB or StringC is shorter than String A. I inferred that the strings that you will be testing will be pre-validated as being all equal in length.